# Excel number format - units of hundredths, thousandths, millionths

Tags: microsoft-excel

For custom number formatting in Excel, there are endless search results to display numbers in units of hundreds, thousands, millions, etc..

Like, to display bits in units of kilo and mega for example
[image: displaying in kb and mb]

I would like to go in the opposite direction and display values in units of milli (thousandths) or micro (millionths). Like this:
[image: milli micro]

The internet is silent on that. I'm guessing it's not possible?
I tried playing with scientific notation as a starting point, to see if I could then get rid of the "E-xx" part, but I couldn't find a way to tell Excel to hide matched groups. I thought maybe there was some sort of regular expression notation.
[image: milli micro in scientific notation]

Is it fair to say there is no way to do this, strictly using the custom formatting specifiers?

Comment: Yes, it is fair to say that.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not quite sure how you'd like the column to appear, there is an example in LibreOffice *Calc* below that might get you started in the right direction.

[image: Calc User-defined formatting]

- The column B is calculated as 1,000,000 times A, i.e., converting seconds to microseconds. One could define it as 1,048,576 times the first to convert megabytes to bytes, and so forth.
- The format for column B is user defined. In the example, `" µs"` is added to show microseconds inline. Hopefully, *Excel* has similar capability.

No, this is not really an answer, but it might give you an idea for an answer that *you* can add.